# Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. With HOC

Tags: node.js, typescript, react-native

I've implemented an HOC that hide a component if the user hasn't subscribed,after that, i got that red error that I can't understand.

> Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

Here is the HOC :

```
const withSubscription = <P extends object>(
  BaseComponent: ComponentType<P>,
  pack: Pack,
): ((props: P) => ReactElement | null) => (props: P): null | ReactElement => {
  const { subscription } = useSubscription();
  const subscriptionIndex = useMemo(() => subscription?.findIndex((subscriptionPack) => subscriptionPack === pack), [pack]);

  if (subscriptionIndex === -1) {
    return null;
  }

  return <BaseComponent {...props} />;
};
```

I've applied the HOC to a button :

```
const Button: FC = (props) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={[
        styles.cartButtonContainer,
        { backgroundColor: primaryColor },
      ]}
      onPress={handleAddProduct}
    >
      <Icon
        name={"cart-arrow-down"}
        materialCom
        style={{ marginRight: 0 }}
        size={25}
        color={secondaryColor}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

export default withSubscription(CartButton, Pack.CLICK_COLLECT);
```

And here is how I call it :

```
return (
   <Button onPress={...}/>
)
```

There is something i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Cannot reproduce your error. Check the [playground here](https://tsplay.dev/mAVQXW).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, it’s a react native related warning, so it doesn’t appear in the ts compiler